# Sort Multiple Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for some advice on how to approach this, I would like to sort a spreadsheet across 2 sheets using a google script.  I know how to use sort () but it only works on a single sheet. First sheet has 2 columns, student name and student number, second sheet has columns student name and student number linked from the first sheet (ex. =Sheet1!A1) and additional columns to enter student marks.  Problem is if I use sort on the first sheet then the mark columns will no longer align with the student names and numbers because they are referenced from the first sheet. I know combining into 1 sheet would solve this but I need them in different sheets as it's part of a bigger project.
I could use some advice on how to approach this using a google script.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33172975/1677912) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `VLOOKUP` in your second sheet instead of direct references. Then you can rearrange the rows in Sheet1 all you want without affecting Sheet2. e.g. `=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!$A$1:$B,2,false)`

Place that formula into all cells in column B of the second sheet.
I'm assuming that the student name is always in column A and the student number in column B.

Comment: I tried entering VLOOKUP formula in all cells of column B of the second sheet but the marks columns will no longer match up when sorting sheet 1. What am I doing wrong?  Here is a sample sheet, [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B4HVCDjAyO3v7TQxqdwJ_xWLX0CODdGmTFm0gZ2PamY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I modified your example. It only works if you put in the student number as a number in each sheet and not as a reference. Try sorting the first sheet by column C and you will see that the second sheet is not changing.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kZhp6omMuMl01PFFZWO2oSIK1a-EC-LL5bSkh6jFeHA/edit?usp=sharing