# Script modification to transfer data from one work sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My first attempt at script writing.  I am trying to create an inventory tracker.  I found a good discussion and script located at [Here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/yhpYJHAWbTQ) but I need a small modification. This script uses a "dump" page which would be my "purchase" workbook.  When items are entered into the dump page, the script determines where the items are transferred based on the "values" of col 1, and col 2.

I am looking to transfer data based on just the item without the need for conditions.  My current columns are:
Date, Item, Vendor, Qty, Cost

Code from link is below

```html
var fedId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var fedSheetName = 'Sheet1';
var dhlId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var dhlSheetName = 'Sheet1';
var upsId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var upsSheetName = 'Sheet1';
var dumpSheetName = 'Sheet1';
var firstColToWatch = 2;
var secondColToWatch = 1;

function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Transfer')
        .addItem('Transfer rows', 'moveRows')
        .addToUi();
}


function moveRows() {


    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getActiveSheet();
    var rows = [];
    var writeBack = [];
    var range = s.getDataRange();
    var val = range.getValues()
        .forEach(function (r, i) {
            if (r[1].substring(0, 3) == "DHL" && r[0] == 'Watches') { //&& is used because both conditions need to evaluate to 'true'
                  moveToSheet(dhlId, dhlSheetName, r);// Javascript arrays are zero-indexed. So r[0] is column 1...
                rows.push(i + 1);
            } else if (r[1].substring(0, 3) == "DHL" && r[0] == 'Shirts') {
                  moveToSheet(dhlId, dhlSheetName, r);
                rows.push(i + 1);
            } else if (r[1].substring(0, 3) == "UPS" && r[0] == 'Shoes')  {
                moveToSheet(upsId, upsSheetName, r);
                rows.push(i + 1);
            } else if (r[1].substring(0, 3) == "UPS" && r[0] == 'Pants')  {
                moveToSheet(upsId, upsSheetName, r);
                rows.push(i + 1);
            } else if (r[1].substring(0, 5) == "FEDEX") { //using susbstring (first 5 letters of value in col 2) so that we can match anything starting with...
                moveToSheet(fedId, fedSheetName, r);
                rows.push(i + 1);
            } else {
                writeBack.push(r);
            }
        });
    s.clear();
    s.getRange(1, 1, writeBack.length, writeBack[0].length)
        .setValues(writeBack);
}


function moveRow(e) {


    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = e.range.rowStart;
    if (s.getName() !== "Sheet1" || e.range.columnStart !== firstColToWatch || e.value == "") return;
    var val = s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn())
        .getValues()[0];
    if (e.value.indexOf("DHL") !== -1 && val[0] == "Watches") {
        moveToSheet(dhlId, dhlSheetName, val);
        s.deleteRow(r);
    } else if (e.value.indexOf("DHL") !== -1 && val[0] == "Shirts") {
        moveToSheet(dhlId, dhlSheetName, val);
        s.deleteRow(r);
    } else if (e.value.indexOf("UPS") !== -1 && val[0] == "Shoes") {
        moveToSheet(upsId, upsSheetName, val);
        s.deleteRow(r);
    } else if (e.value.indexOf("UPS") !== -1 && val[0] == "Pants") {
        moveToSheet(upsId, upsSheetName, val);
        s.deleteRow(r);
    } else if (e.value.indexOf("FEDEX") !== -1) {
        moveToSheet(fedId, fedSheetName, val);
        s.deleteRow(r);
    }


}


function moveToSheet(Id, sheetName, val) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Id)
        .getSheetByName(sheetName)
        .appendRow(val);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Solutions given in this related SO post - [Synchronize independent spreadsheet rows, filled by IMPORTRANGE()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959875/synchronize-independent-spreadsheet-rows-filled-by-importrange/33172975#33172975) might help.