# Appending data to a record using Google Sheets Query function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm hoping someone can help fix my solution, or offer an alternative suggestion I could investigate.

Long story short, I'm building a Job Request Google Form for work, this should allow staff to make requests in one of 4 categories (IT, Keys, Maintenance, OHS) but keep the tracking of those jobs separate as they're all carried out by different teams.

I've built the Google Form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe8TKXDE2kGJmSdkeWaO1jefxTsjYy_RRwR_6Ta-VZtQMq8Yg/viewform?usp=sf_link

And I've built most of a spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A92hVHldgM4Z97mPh0S0wZfKgVbNCFho7KU_6bH038c/edit#gid=1156025096

The Spreadsheet uses the Query function to split the requests into each of their 4 categories and provides space for the response team to track their progress.

The problem is: As new jobs are added to each category the older jobs move down by a row but the response teams progress will not move relative to job in which they should be tracked against. This is because the jobs are dynamic (returned by the query) where as the progress tracking is static (entered by the response team).

I someone has a solution.

Thank you,

Peter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronize independent spreadsheet rows, filled by IMPORTRANGE()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959875/synchronize-independent-spreadsheet-rows-filled-by-importrange)

Comment: Thank you. I think that this will work, but I'm unable to make the script run within my workbook. 

I have made the script work in a different workbook, but not the one I need it for. 

So, I have changed the sheet ID, and I have used Find/Replace to change the sheets "Items" and "Orders" to reflect the names in my sheet. 

The issue occurs with Line 29. 
var orderData = sheet2.getSheetValues(1, keyCol, lastRow, lastCol-keyCol+1);

The error says: The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. Line 29, file "Code")

I hope you can help. Thank you.