# 2 spreadsheets, IMPORTRANGE update references when adding/deleting rows

Tags: google-sheets, rows, google-sheets-formula, importrange

How can I get the `IMPORTRANGE` function to update references in Spreadsheet #2 if I've added/deleted rows to Spreadsheet #1?

Test docs:

[Spreadsheet1: "S1"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY/edit?usp=sharing)

[Spreadsheet2: "S2"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R1T6YSfEQdn4qVcULJ1hNehEfDBZJNaTv1jJpaALJQk/edit?usp=sharing)

All the answers I've found say

1. just duplicate/copy sheet from S1 to S2 (but I want S2 to dynamically update when I update S1. don't want to update both S1 and S2 each time)
2. Use this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959875/synchronize-independent-spreadsheet-rows-filled-by-importrange), but I got an error saying the range was wrong
3. use an array (not sure how to do that...)
4. use [`address`](https://www.coalmarch.com/insights/fill-import-range) feature (but this did not work either)
5. use `VLOOKUP` array (but my spreadsheets do not have the matching column headers)
6. tried using absolute reference $L$48 but this didnt work either

Would appreciate some assistance figuring this out. I need L47, M47 (S1) to populate into A2, A3 (S2). My actual source spreadsheet (not linked) has tons of data (range A1:Z55) and I add/delete/move rows often.

If I add a row to S1, how can I ensure `L47` will update in S2 to `L48`? Is the `address` feature the best solution or is an `array` better?

Comment: So you are trying to import data from a single cell reference ID from one SS to another?  And the issue is that adding/deleting rows changes the reference?  Can you just put your reference data at the top so that row manipulations don't affect it?

Comment: @RonKloberdanz unfortunately cannot put ref data at top. It’s a big data table that has to be sorted/filtered for others. The 2nd SS summarizes the info in S1. ‘IMPORTRANGE’ would be perfect if it could allow adding/deleting of rows/columns. It allows for dynamic updating, just doesn’t update references when new rows/columns are added/deleted

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I feel that your example sheets aren't matching exactly what you are asking to do.  You show in your sheet S1 that specific ranges of data can be filtered/sorted.  What is stopping you from moving the data in L47 to A47?

Comment: @RonKloberdanz the test sheets are just samples. My actual workbooks have like 10+ sheets each, sensitive data, and lots of scripts and formulas on each sheet. I made the test sheets to give an example of what I was trying to accomplish without sharing any sensitive info and without spending hours trying to recreate/redact test sheets. I only need about 10 cells from S1 referenced in S2, but I only asked about 2 in my question since I can extrapolate after we figure out which approach works best

Comment: Are the cells you want to reference part of the data or separate?

Comment: @RonKloberdanz cells I want are in S1. I want them to show in S2, even after adding/deleting rows. Technically they’re separate since they’re in diff workbooks. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178505/discussion-between-ron-kloberdanz-and-que-syrah-sarah).

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved by adding an extra column far away, where it can be hidden and then populating this column by joining desired set of cells by unique separator until split will occur on the second spreadsheet. note that:

- adding or deleting rows will not affect dynamicity of `IMPORTRANGE`
- adding deleting columns will break all imported data
- there is no need for an extra column if there is a unique separator per every `IMPORTRANGE` of data and the search is applied always to such unique separator

in this particular case, there was used column **AG** from which `IMPORTRANGE` was fed.

in **Spreadsheet1** in **Sheet1!AG** (no matter of row number) there are formulas which `JOIN` content of **L50** and **M50** as well as the content of **L51** and **M51**, etc... (no matter if it's done directly or indirectly as far as the output is `TEXT`):

```
=JOIN("¤"; L50; MIN(FILTER(L:L; ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*banana*"; P:P))     
                               +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*banana*"; Q:Q))
                               +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*banana*"; R:R)))))
```

> **outputing:** **`next banana¤30-Aug-2004`**

---

```
=JOIN("¤"; L51; MIN(FILTER(L:L; ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*orange*"; P:P))     
                               +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*orange*"; Q:Q))
                               +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*orange*"; R:R)))))
```

> **outputing:** **`next orange¤2-Oct-2003`**

---

```
=JOIN("♥"; L52; AVERAGE(FILTER(L:L; ISNUMBER(SEARCH("orange"; P:P))
                                   +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("orange"; Q:Q))
                                   +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("orange"; R:R)))))
```

> **outputing:** **`X♥25-Sep-2013`**

---

```
=JOIN("♀"; L53; MIN(FILTER(L5:L48; ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*banana*"; Q5:Q48))
                                  *ISNUMBER(SEARCH("open";     R5:R48)))))
```

> **outputing:** **`next banana♀20-Aug-2000`**

---

```
=JOIN("♂"; L54; AVERAGEIFS(M5:M48; R5:R48; "open", 
                                   Q5:Q48; "*banana*"))
```

> **outputing:** **`avg days open (banana)♂74.41`**

---

```
=JOIN("♪"; L55; Q50/Q51)
```

> **outputing:** **`util♪0.370544987`**

---

```
=JOIN("♫"; L56; MINIFS(M5:M48; R5:R48; "open", 
                               Q5:Q48; "*banana*"))
```

> **outputing:** **`newest (mo)♫3.48`**

---

```
=JOIN("¤"; L57; M56*30.5)
```

> **outputing:** **`newest(days)¤106.2580645`**

---

```
=JOIN("♤"; L58; M58)
```

> **outputing:** **`avg LMT♤25051.35484`**

at this point, it doesn't matter if the format of joined cells is outputting elsehow (eg. 2nd part of the output should be formatted as **`$`**, **`%`**, **`mm/dd/yyyy`**) because in **Spreadsheet2** after splitting you can format it back as you wish

in **Spreadsheet2** you are free to paste following formula at any column and any row as well as you are free to:

- add or delete any rows in **Spreadsheet1**
- and add or delete any rows or columns in **Spreadsheet2**

---

```
 =SPLIT(
        ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
                        QUERY(


        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

        "select Col1 where Col1 ='"&
        FILTER(

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

                   ISNUMBER(
                            SEARCH("banana";

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000"))

                   ))
                                    &"'"); 
                        1; 1); 
       "¤"; 1; 0)
```

this basically `SEARCH`es for text value `"banana"` in Spreadsheet1 under Sheet1 from range AG1:AG1000 and feed it to the `FILTER` which feeds criterion of `QUERY` which is `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`ed to return one entry and that entry is `SPLIT` after unique separator `"¤"` (used earlier in `JOIN`) into two columns at the same row. and that's it.

if the content of cell **L50** is static like `banana` **and also unique per column** you can `SEARCH` for `"banana"` otherwise you need to use **unique separator per column** and `SEARCH` for such separator instead of `"banana"`

for a successful linkup, you need to be sure that separator in `SPLIT` matches separator in `JOIN` (`"¤"`). you can use any symbol you wish as the separator (**http://www.i2symbol.com/symbols**)

**example:** for formula **`=JOIN("♤"; L58; M58)`** you can use:

```
 =SPLIT(
        ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
                        QUERY(


        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

        "select Col1 where Col1 ='"&
        FILTER(

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

                   ISNUMBER(
                            SEARCH("lmt";

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000"))

                   ))
                                    &"'"); 
                        1; 1); 
       "♤"; 1; 0)
```

**or**

```
 =SPLIT(
        ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
                        QUERY(


        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

        "select Col1 where Col1 ='"&
        FILTER(

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

                   ISNUMBER(
                            SEARCH("♤";

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000"))

                   ))
                                    &"'"); 
                        1; 1); 
       "♤"; 1; 0)
```

**or**

```
 =SPLIT(
        ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
                        QUERY(


        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

        "select Col1 where Col1 ='"&
        FILTER(

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

                   ISNUMBER(
                            SEARCH("avg LMT";

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000"))

                   ))
                                    &"'"); 
                        1; 1); 
       "♤"; 1; 0)
```