# Making manually-added cells automatically move along with imported ranges in Google Sheets?

Tags: database, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For data analysis purposes, I need to manually add information in the columns right beside an imported range. It generally doesn't cause any issues and works well. However, whenever the imported data shifts rows (i.e. a new row was added in the middle of the original sheet), the manually-added info no longer matches the data -it either ends up in one row above or below. Basically, it's not in-sync with the needed data.

Is there a way to kind of "fixate" the manually-added information to the same row as the imported data? So that if the order changes in the original sheet, it won't mess up the new one.

I've been using the code shared by @Mogsdad [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959875/synchronize-independent-spreadsheet-rows-filled-by-importrange). However, it is only syncing the info on the "key column" and not the rest of the data in the columns after it.

Attaching screenshots for reference:

This is how it usually looks (the third column is the "key")[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2zEA.png)

And this is what happens when the rows in the imported range change:[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HQnT.png)

The code seems to be working, just not for all the columns.

Comment: Review: Adding screenshots and/or (pseudo) code will probably help a lot in understanding your problem.

Comment: I cannot understand about `Is there a way to kind of "fixate" the manually-added information to the same row as the imported data?`. Especially, I cannot understand about `the manually-added information to the same row as the imported data`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! Sure thing, I have two workbooks (1 & 2). I imported the data from workbook 1 to workbook 2, but I also had to manually add data in workbook 2 (additional details basically). 

The issue is that the information I manually added in workbook 2 is not synchronized with the imported data. So if anything changes in Workbook 1, it doesn’t sync with the info I added in workbook 2.